# How to convert NSString to NSDate with specific format

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm sorry if this has been asked before but I did a lot of checking and I can't seem to find an answer. :(

I have a string "2013-05-7 05:53:15 +0000" and I want to convert it to a NSDate so I can compare it with the current date and time. I can't figure out how to do this.  :(  I successfully converted it but it changes the look of the string and I want it to be exactly 2013-05-7 05:53:15 +0000 as that is the same format I have the other NSDate item.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

I am confused. ;)  new to objective C.  old VB / older C programmer from the 80s trying to figure this stuff out.  Thank you for your help. :)

My code looks like this:

```
    NSDateFormatter *df1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
//    [df1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"];
    [df1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
    df1.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"EN"];
  NSDate *titemdate1 = [df1 dateFromString: itemdate];
```

what i have is two dates.  one that is the last date the app was run and the other is the date of the item i'm pulling down using JSON.  I want to compare the two dates (which are in string format as stated above).  when I do a NSLog of the strings they look perfect but when i convert to NSDate to compare i have problems.  any ideas?

Comment: Why "without format", and what do you mean by that?  Easiest (by far) approach is to use NSDateFormatter.

Comment: (And NSDate objects don't have a "format" -- they're pure time.)

Comment: (I suspect that's your confusion.  You can always compare two NSDate objects using the methods defined for NSDate.  The way they print has nothing to do with the internal representation.)

Comment: yes - i am confused ;)  please see m edits above... maybe this might help you guys understand where i'm at.  Sorry if i come off clueless. I sort of am and that is why i'm asking for help!  :)  I've written this entire app by figuring it out but this last bit I just can't hack together. :(

Comment: You don't define what your "problems" are.  One may have to do with timezone -- when you use NSDateFormatter the current timezone is assumed, unless the date has a timezone specified.  Yours does, but you're not reading it with that format.  Date format patterns are defined [here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns).  You need "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z" to read that format.

Comment: Note that you normally shouldn't compare dates for equality, but should use `compare` and check the result against NSOrderedAscending or NSOrderedDescending.

Answer (score 1):

Try with using below code..

```
-(NSDate*)dateFromJsonString:(NSString*)string
{   
    NSDateFormatter *inputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
    NSDate *xExpDate = [inputFormatter dateFromString:string];

    return xExpDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should know that if you convert the dateString to date and do NSLog of date, it returns the GMT time, which will be different from your system time in most cases. So if you are getting the string in correct format, then the date formatter is probably working fine. To check this, just convert your formatted date to string and print the output.

```
NSLog(@"formatted date: %@",[df1 stringFromDate:titemdate1]);
```

If that doesnt change anything and the output is still wrong, try changing the format of your formatter.

```
[df1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
```